# Rust: borrow checker in infinite loop

Tags: rust, infinite-loop, borrow-checker

I'm currently building an application with a main loop. Settings are added to the struct as references to avoid boxing. The problem is, even though it seems perfectly valid, the borrow checker does not validate infinite loops. As an example, this does not compile:

```
struct Demo<'a> {
    data: Vec<&'a u8>,
}

impl<'a> Demo<'a> {
    fn new(data: Vec<&'a u8>) -> Self {
        Demo { data }
    }

    fn bug(mut self) -> ! {
        let a = 8;
        {
            self.data.push(&a);
            {
                self.forever();
            }
        }
    }

    fn forever(self) -> ! {
        loop {
            for dat in &self.data {
                println!("{}", dat);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![&1, &1, &2, &3];
    Demo::new(v).bug();
}
```

My question is: how could I refactor the code above to avoid boxing the data, but still being able to use a main loop.

Comment: You are telling the compiler that the pointers stored in `data` (and hence the whole struct `Demo`) must be valid for at least `'a` , yet the value you push has a shorter lifespan - i.e. the instance of the struct outlives it. Although thi sis not an issue for your case, it's still a violation of the lifetime rules.

Comment: "Settings are added to the struct as references to avoid boxing" – If boxes are the alternative, should `Data` simply _own_ the settings instead? This would solve your problem in a trivial way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within an `impl<'a> Demo<'a>`, all the `self`s have the exact same type, for the exact same `'a`. But in your case, you are trying to shorten the lifetime. You can do this by rebinding `self`:

```rust
let mut this = self;
// the compiler infers that `this` must have a shorter lifetime:
this.data.push(&a);
this.forever();
```

([link to the playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d1a8a40cbe1700d863e4a181de50628e))

Your other example can be fixed in a [similar way](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=04ba718d3ca5cb87f893aea7db3ebdbc).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not so much that the borrow checker can't see the infinite loop but that you are actively lying to the compiler. When constructing the `Demo<'a>` in `main()`, the lifetime `'a` is a distinct lifetime (bound to the scope of `main()`). Within `bug()` you now push a new reference which has to last as long as *the lifetime 'a has already been established to be*. There is no way out of this.

You can, however, create references which are guaranteed to live at least as long as *any* lifetime:

```
fn bug(mut self) -> ! {
    let a: &'static u8 = &8;
    {
        self.data.push(a);
        {
            self.forever();
        }
    }
}
```

This will work, because no matter what `'a` is, `'static`will live at least as long.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the problem is that the reference is effectively not static, only with a lifetime longer than bug.

Comment: Could you post a more realistic example then? Where is that lifetime coming from? Remember that while this looks like an infinite loop, things can panic, stacks unwind and "fire and forget" lifetimes become unsafe memory all of the sudden.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=88e4f92f0585143f0bbb833a81e02a99 Is closer to what I would want. It works fine if exit is inlined in main, but this is not really optimal from a user perspective

Comment: `let a = &|_shell: &Demo| {}; self.callbacks.push(a);` will compile. Notice how the creation of the reference is moved.